# Concatenate two values in a pair of 2 tuples

Tags: python-3.x

So I'm trying to create a function where it combines the elements of a tuple.

So for example:

`[(1,2),("Hi","Bye")]` will become `['12', 'HiBye']` after the function is implemented.

How can I achieve this in Python?

Answer (score 1):

For pairs, you can do:

```
>>> list(map(lambda pair:"%s%s"%pair, [(1,2),("Hi","Bye")]))
['12', 'HiBye']
```

or if you want to handle arbitrary tuples, not just pairs:

```
>>> list(map(lambda l:''.join(map(str, l)), [(1,2),("Hi","Bye")]))
['12', 'HiBye']
>>> list(map(lambda l:''.join(map(str, l)), [(1,2,3),("Hi","Bye","Ciao")]))
['123', 'HiByeCiao']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
L = [(1, 2), ('Hi', 'Bye')]
L = list(map(lambda t : str(t[0]) + str(t[1]), L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try combining `map()` and `reduce()` :

```
import operator

lst = [("1", "2"), ("c", "d")]
map(lambda x: reduce(operator.concat, x, ""), lst)
```

The matching items must be concatenatable, i.e. you need to convert them to e.g. strings first. Or include it in the code :

```
import operator

lst = [(1, 2, 3, 52), ("c", "d")]
map(lambda x: reduce(operator.concat, map(str, x), ""), lst)
```

Using `string.join()` is also possible (and probably more pythonic):

```
lst = [(1, 2, 3, 52), ("c", "d")]
map(lambda x: ''.join(map(str, x)), lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension:

```
myList = [(1,2),("Hi","Bye")]

answer = [str(t[0]) + str(t[1]) for t in myList]
```